# Can directive's scope when false create new objects and functions.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am little new to this directive thing in Angularjs.

While going through scopes in directives, I found out that they can be declared in three forms, `scope: false(shared scope)`, `scope: true(inherited scope)`, `scope: {}(isolated scope)`.

```
.directive('smsDownloadSampleFile',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    template: '<input type="button" class="btn cur-p btn-info pull-right" value="Download Sample Upload File" ng-click="getSampleFile()">',
    link: function(scope,element,attr) {

      scope.getSampleFile=function() {
        // console.log("Getting sample file on");
      }

      DS=$scope;
    }
  }
})
```

So I had created this directive, but I cannot access this method `getSampleFile` in my parent scope. As far I have learnt is that when `scope=false` then it doesn't creates a new scope, rather it shares parent scope. If so then, why I can't access that method in my parent scope.

Please help me in clearing this doubt and learning something new.

Comment: Aren't you redefining the function?

Comment: No sir. Its a new function.

Comment: But if you're sharing the same exact scope as the parent, aren't you overwriting the function on the parent? If you had `scope: true` you would be creating a new function, and the one on the parent would still exist.

Comment: Anyway, you're probably better off with isolated scope so there are no assumptions about what exists on the parent (everything gets passed in).

Comment: That is what I want to know sir, Is childscope allowed to create new objects or functions when it is sharing the scope.?

Comment: The scope given to the directive is literally the same exact object as the scope of the parent. You are "allowed" to do whatever you want to that object, but you can easily overwrite things on the parent. This is why isolated is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

With `scope: false` the directive receives the same exact scope object as the parent. So you are overwriting the function on the parent when you do:

```
scope.getSampleFile=function() { ... }
```

Isolated scope is usually recommended because then you have to explicitly pass data into the directive, and the parent cannot be overwritten (unless you go out of your way to do so).

Comment: Yes sir, I have understood that I can overwrite the already created objects and functions of parent scope. But can I create new objects and functions in chidlscope which are not already present in parent scope and would that be reflected in parent scope?

Comment: Yes they are the same exact object (but you probably shouldn't do that)